# jquery tablesorter filter match-any doesn't support upper case searches

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm looking at the "jquery tablersorter" filter widget, v2.17.8

I would like to implement the external search filter but it doesn't return any results when i use an upper case letter. This is the reproducible on the demo page. (search 'ph' returns 1 result, search 'Ph' returns 0 results. I tried it in Chrome and IE)

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-any-match.html

Is there a configurable option to fix this behavior? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This issue has been fixed in v2.18.0.

Comment: what is the current stable release? when I download, I get the v2.17.8 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the widget since there's no documented difference between `data-column="1"` and `data-column="all"`. It also [doesn't work](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-external-inputs.html) using the `bindSearch` function.

Since the search performs as expected in any individual column (ignoring case) but does not for the search all option you might want to [submit an issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues).